# copy all records from a DB to another with identical schema but different collation

Tags: sql-server, database, collation

I have a DB_A with a collation type (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) and its proper schema, stored procedure etc.
I was able to reproduce an identical DB_B with a different collation type (Latin1_General_CI_AS) but the same schema, stored procedure and so on.

I need now to migrate all the records of whole DB_A to DB_B, that is identical schema but different collation type.
After that test if that work with my software.
Is there anyone suggesting a tool, a procedure or a good practice to follow in order to finally carry on all the records from my source DB_A to my destination DB_B in the mostly automated way avoiding any kind of data-lost?
thanks

Comment: You can take backup and change collation later,you can use ssis export import...

Comment: ehi thanks. could you be much more specific on the procedure you suggested?

Comment: How to change database collation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx

Comment: I am saying backup restore is the fastest way to transfer data,what is the issue with this

Comment: Just do a backup / restore, and change collation on the restored copy.